# Find sublist of indices for a list of items in another list with multiple occurrences or None in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nested-lists, sublist

Lookup items from list2 in list1, and return indices in sublist for each item in list2.
If no occurence is found return None.

```
list1 = ['fq','ab','opn','ef','cd','ef','opn','kl','fq','str','opn','ab','cd']
list2 = ['ab','cd','ef','ed','fq']
found_item_index = [code]  
found_item_index = [[1,11], [4,12], [3,5], [None], [0]]
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
list1 = ['fq', 'ab', 'opn', 'ef', 'cd', 'ef', 'opn', 'kl', 'fq', 'str', 'opn', 'ab', 'cd']
list2 = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'ed', 'fq']

def find_index(lst, item):
    pos = [i for i, lst_item in enumerate(lst) if lst_item == item]
    return pos or [None]

found_item_index = [find_index(list1, item) for item in list2]
print(found_item_index)
```

Output

```
[[1, 11], [4, 12], [3, 5], [None], [0, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute force solution can be applied if the number of items in `list1` and `list2` are smaller. We can search for each element of `list2` in `list1` and then store the indexes of `list1` in an empty list. Then we can append this list to `found_item_index` if there are any search result. Otherwise, we will append a list with only `[None]` element to the `found_item_index`.

```
list1 = ['fq','ab','opn','ef','cd','ef','opn','kl','fq','str','opn','ab','cd']
list2 = ['ab','cd','ef','ed','fq']
found_item_index = []
for search_item in list2:
    search_result = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if search_item == list1[i]:
            search_result.append(i)
    if len(search_result)>0:
        found_item_index.append(search_result)
    else:
        found_item_index.append([None])
        
print(found_item_index)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 11], [4, 12], [3, 5], [None], [0, 8]]
```

Time Complexity: `O(n*n)`

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple iteration

**Ex:**

```
list1 = ['fq','ab','opn','ef','cd','ef','opn','kl','fq','str','opn','ab','cd']
list2 = ['ab','cd','ef','ed','fq']


check_val = {}                             #--> {'fq': [0, 8], 'ab': [1, 11], 'opn': [2, 6, 10], 'ef': [3, 5], 'cd': [4, 12], 'kl': [7], 'str': [9]}
for idx, val in enumerate(list1):
    check_val.setdefault(val, []).append(idx)

found_item_index = [check_val.get(i, [None]) for i in list2]      
print(found_item_index)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 11], [4, 12], [3, 5], [None], [0, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the output you want:

```
list1 = ['fq','ab','opn','ef','cd','ef','opn','kl','fq','str','opn','ab','cd'] 
list2 = ['ab','cd','ef','ed','fq']

output = [([i for i, x in enumerate(list1) if x == obj] if obj in list1 else [None]) for obj in list2]

print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NumPy as:

```
import numpy as np
found_item_index = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
    found_item_index.append(list(np.where(np.array(list1) == list2[i])[0]) 
                            if list(np.where(np.array(list1) == list2[i])[0]) else None)
found_item_index
```